# Sum with parameter convergence

Tags: calculus

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})^p}\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right).
$$
For which values of the parameter p is it convergent?

Answer (score 1):

You series is asymptotically equivalent to
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n^{1+p/2}} $$
that is convergent for $\color{red}{p>0}$. That happens since 
$ 2\sqrt{n}<\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}<2\sqrt{n+1}$ and:
$$ \log\frac{n-1}{n+1} = \log\left(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\right) = -\frac{2}{n+1}+O\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right).$$